# How to conditionally add data to a column in an Excel file based on the keys and values of a python dictionary while keeping other columns consistent

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Let's assume I have a Microsoft Excel (.xlxs) file with the following three columns and 4 rows with headers:

```
**Item Number** **Type**   **Field Value**
      001           1            20
      002           2            NaN
      003           1            NaN
      004           3            NaN
```

Where NaN are empty fields in the Excel sheet and Pandas interprets those empty fields as NaN

and a python dictionary with the following Keys and Values:

```
dict_a =  {001:20, 002:10, 003:20, 004:30}
```

Where the keys of the dictionary will correlate to the first column of the Excel file and the values in the dictionary are what I would like to append into the third column of the Excel file.  So my ideal Excel file output would be:

```
**Item Number**  **Type**   **Field Value**
      001           1            20
      002           2            10
      003           1            20
      004           3            30
```

Where the values of the dictionary are appended to the Excel file by consulting the keys of the dictionary and correlating them to the first column of the Excel sheet but all the while keeping the association of association of the second column to the first column consistent.  The actual excel file has several thousand rows, these are just for an example of the problem I am facing.

I have successfully created a dictionary called dict_a with the correct key and value pairs and imported the excel file using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
dict_a =  {001:20, 002:10, 003:20, 004:30}
filename = 'Item_File.xlxs'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
item_num_col = df['Item Number']
field_val_col = df['Field Value']

#all the above works just fine, the below is where I hit a wall, 

for value in field_val_col:
    for num in item_num_col:
        if num in dict_a.keys():
            value = dict_a.values()
```

But this is not working and I am a little lost on the syntax to make Python correlate values in an excel with the keys and values in a dictionary.

This solution will need to be compatible with Python 2.7 and the pandas module if at all possible.  I am attempting to create this code on a government computer so I can not download Python 3+ or other modules like OpenPyXL.

Thank you for any help you can provide, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track! Let's add some debug code to see what is going wrong.

```
for value in field_val_col:
    for num in item_num_col:
        if num in dict_a.keys():
            value = dict_a.values()
            print(value)
```

For your example given, this will output:

```
dict_values([20, 10, 20, 30])
dict_values([20, 10, 20, 30])
dict_values([20, 10, 20, 30])
...repeats 16 times...
```

Not exactly what we want. Not only are you setting the `value` variable to all the values of the dictionary each time, you aren't actually doing anything with `value`.

In order to write to a panda's dataframe, you can use the `df.at()` method, feel free to read about it (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

This turns your above code into the following:

```
import pandas as pd
dict_a =  {1:20, 2:10, 3:20, 4:30}
filename = 'Item_File.xlxs'
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
item_num_col = df['Item Number']
field_val_col = df['Field Value']

for num in item_num_col:
    if num in dict_a:
        # you may want to do something else here. It looks like indicies in excel start at 1, where
        # indicies from pandas start at 0. this is why the num-1 is the key instead of num
        field_val_col.at[num-1] = dict_a[num]

print(df)
```

This will output:

```
   Item Number  Type  Field Value
0            1     1         20.0
1            2     2         10.0
2            3     1         20.0
3            4     3         30.0
```